# GUI on Windows 10 x64 with high DPI screen

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows

OK - so this might be a silly question but I have literally just moved back to windows after 10 years on mac. I've just downloaded the GUI and the daemon is currently synching... BUT the GUI is tiny on my screen! I am at a loss as to how I manipulate the graphics to make the GUI larger (so I can see the damn thing) without adversely affecting all the other icons on screen. Thanks!

Comment: What is your screen resolution?  (1920x1080? 1366x720? etc)

Comment: currently 3840x2160 on a 15" laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-core/issues/343) that has been reported a week ago and not yet fixed.